# A form of a skew symmetric mapping of rank two on a space with a nondegenerate symmetric quadratic form

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $B: E\times E \rightarrow K$ be a symmetric nondegenerate bilinear form on a finite dimensional space $E$ over a field $K$ with characteristic different from $2$.

Let $f: E\rightarrow E$ be a linear and  skew-symmetric mapping:
$$
B(f(x),y)=-B(x,f(y)) \textrm{ for } x,y\in E,
$$
of rank $2$ such that $t\circ t=0$. It have to be of the form
$$
f(x)=B(x,c)a+B(y,d)b
$$

for $x\in E$, where $a,b,c,d \in E$ and $a,b$ are linearly independent (because $t(x)=\alpha(x)a+\beta(x)b$ for $x\in E$, where $a,b \in E$ are linearly independent and $\alpha, \beta\in E^*$; since $B$ induces an isomorphism from $E$ onto $E^*$ we have $\alpha(x)=B(x,c)$, $\beta(x)=B(x,d) $ for $x\in E$ and some $c,d\in E$)

What about $c,d$?  Is $c=tb, d=-ta$ for some scalar $t$?

Comment: Have you tried logarithms?